# convert android hashmap to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Java `HashMap` populated as

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
    myMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
}
```

And I'm trying to convert this to Kotlin. I tried the way below, but I'm getting null value in it.

```
var myMap : HashMap<String, Int>? = null
for (i in objects){
    //myMap?.put(i, objects.indexOf(i))
    myMap?.put("sample", 3)
    System.out.println("myMapInForLoop" + myMap)
}
```

It prints `I/System.out: myMapInForLoopnull`.

I've tried using `hashMapOf` function, but it allows only 1 value, so I cannot put that in `myMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can instantiate the `HashMap` directly. Instead of a for-loop you could then use `forEachIndexed` for example (if `objects` is an `Array` or `Iterable`).

```
val myMap = HashMap<String, Int>()
objects.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
    myMap.put(item, index)
    System.out.println("myMapInForLoop" + myMap)
}
```

In your version of the code you get `null`, because you assign it to `myMap`. Also you might have only a single value, because you only set a `"sample"` key for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but you can also use

```
val myMap = objects.withIndex().associateTo(HashMap<String, Int>()) {
    it.value to it.index
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()` if you want to mutate the map within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `myMap`.

```
val list = listOf("hello", "world", "kotlin", "sfyc23")
val myMap = HashMap<String, Int>()
for (i in list.indices) {
    myMap.put(list[i], i)
}
println(myMap)
```